# How to choose (mean, std) for normalization in transfer learning?

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning, pretraining

I'm working on transfer learning based on ResNet50 pretrained model. Basically, I remove the last layer of ResNet50 and add new head layer. Then I train the model with my image dataset.

Obviously, my image dataset has different mean and standard deviation from ResNet50. The transformation of training also involves normalization with mean and std. So, which (mean, std) should I use for the transfer learning?

Should I stick to ResNet50 mean and std, that is (mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])? or should I calculate (mean, std) of my image dataset and apply it?

Answer (score 1):

The normalization step is meant to provide input values to your network that have mean 0 and variance 1. For this, and given that you are going to provide your own data at fine-tuning and inference time, you should compute mean and std from your own training dataset.

Comment: @MorganCheng was the answer helpful?